# Is there a word that describes someone that concentrates and pays attention a lot?

Tags: adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective - not just any word.

Comment: Won't 'attentive' do?

Comment: @Gary I don't think a site aimed at linguists should be condoning questions like 'What is an adjective to describe someone who pays attention a lot?' when a quick look in almost any dictionary would show the derived form. Do you?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't answer self serving rhetorical questions.... sorry.

Comment: I didn't give such a simplistic answer, already suggested in the OP (which I _would_ regard as being self-serving), and I gave you the chance to follow my example.

Comment: Just as I'm giving you the chance to follow mine.

Comment: Some people like to request questions be closed for infracting upon the rules of the site @Anonymous. Without actually advising you (given this is the first question you've posted) where the fault is in your question. All word requests need to be accompanied with an example sentence of how you intend to use the word, e.g., "Bill is ....... he hasn't stopped concentrating all night" That's a simple example, but if you add a sentence to your question in a similar fashion, that illustrates your intended meaning your question will be just fine! :)

Comment: *pensive*.......

Comment: Could you not, at the very least, say who this (imaginary) person is? A student? A judge, a scientist, a watchmaker? Do you need this adjective for a resumè? For a story? You didn't include any research or which adjectives you rejected, you haven't shown how you would use the adjective... so the question looks like a dictionary request. Give me something!?

Answer (score 4):

Another option is

***[Focused](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/focused)***

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Directing a great deal of attention, interest, or activity towards a
>   particular aim.
>
> ‘Darren knows what he wants and he's very focused’
>
> ‘he seems to be very focused on the new challenge’

Answer (score 3):

***[Attentive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/attentive)***

> Paying close attention to something.

Also:

Diligent is close, but not ideal: -

***[Diligent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/diligent)*** (Oxford)

> Having or showing care and conscientiousness in one's work or duties.

Studious is also close semantically, in the definition found at 2.1 in Oxford Living Dictionary:

***[Studious](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/studious)***

> 2.1 Showing great care or attention.

Comment: Why would anyone -1 this answer?! +1 from me.

Comment: @MaxB As Reg Dwight has said, '[W]e write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer.' An adjective related to 'attention' on a site aimed at linguists would seem to qualify, which is why I put it in a 'comment'.

Comment: **Intense** would open the focus a bit.